# having trouble utilizing hypothesis tests

Tags: python, pandas

I need to " calculate the probability
that a team had a relative skill level
less than the Bulls in years 1996-1998.
Assuming that the relative skill of
teams is Normally distributed, calculate
this probability"

I feel like I understand the concept but
cannot find where I messed up to give me
an almost 500% probability.

code below:

## Write your code in this code block section

```
import numpy as np 

        import pandas as pd 
        import scipy.stats as st 

        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

from IPython.display import display, HTML

nba_orig_df = pd.read_csv('nbaallelo.csv') 

nba_orig_df = nba_orig_df[(nba_orig_df['lg_id']=='NBA') & (nba_orig_df['is_playoffs']==0)] 

columns_to_keep = ['game_id','year_id','fran_id','pts','opp_pts','elo_n','opp_elo_n', 'game_location', 'game_result'] 

nba_orig_df = nba_orig_df[columns_to_keep] 

#set year as 1996-1998 

total_your_years_leagues_df = nba_orig_df[(nba_orig_df['year_id'].between(1996, 1998))]  

#calculate n that represents the sample size 

n = len(your_years_leagues_df)
    
#The variable 'elo_n' represents the relative skill of teams
#calculate mean and standard deviation 
    
total_mean = total_your_years_leagues_df['elo_n'].mean()   

total_stdev = total_your_years_leagues_df['elo_n'].std()   

      

#calculate standard error and confidence interval 

total_stderr = total_stdev/(n ** 0.5)  
 
conf_int_95 = st.norm.interval(0.95, total_mean, total_stderr)  

print("95% confidence interval (rounded) for Average Relative Skill (ELO) in the years 1996-1998 = (",  round(conf_int_95[0], 2),",", round(conf_int_95[1], 2),")")  


#set your team as the bulls

your_years_league_df = nba_orig_df[(nba_orig_df['year_id'].between(1996, 1998))]

your_team_df = your_years_league_df[(your_years_league_df['fran_id']=='Bulls')] 

your_team_df = your_team_df.reset_index(drop=True)

#find mean relative skill of the bulls

mean_elo_your_team = your_team_df['elo_n'].mean() 

deg_freedom = n-1


null = mean_elo_your_team

#alt hypothesis is less than null
print()
print(st.ttest_1samp(your_team_df['elo_n'], total_mean))
print()

t_stat = 75.8884

fin_prob = st.t.cdf(t_stat, deg_freedom, total_mean, total_stdev)


print('probability that a team had a relative skill level less than the Bulls in years 1996-1998 is', 4.8650)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you are using the test correct here.

I think what you want to do is that the total_mean (of all teams), with the standard deviation of of that, and compare that to the mean of the Bulls.

```
#find mean relative skill of the bulls
mean_elo_your_team = your_team_df['elo_n'].mean() 
fin_prob = st.norm.cdf(mean_elo_your_team, total_mean, total_stdev)

print('probability that a team had a relative skill level less than the Bulls in years 1996-1998 is', fin_prob)
```

**Output:**

Give probability of 97.32%

```
probability that a team had a relative skill level less than the Bulls in years 1996-1998 is 0.9732205992228153
```